# Why does WPF provide much less support for charts & is using the Silverlight toolkit the only option?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts

The last known update for WPF Toolkit was in 2010 and it has very limited support for charts. So is importing the Silverlight toolkit the only way to create more WPF charts with flexibility (stacked charts) without involving third party?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Oxyplot to create charts in WPF.
Oxyplot is a free chart library. You can download it in your WPF application using Visual studio's inbuilt tool NuGet Package downloader.